# jQuery Mobile can't get object after page transition

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, transition

My mobile page has 2 "pages" (using the multi-page template of jQuery Mobile).
Now i have a language selector (dropdown). This selector appears on both pages.

Relevant code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/style/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="scripts/javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/javascript/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/javascript/translations.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <div class="formContent" data-role="page" id="one">
                <div data-role="header" class="ui-header-fixed">
                    <div data-role="navbar">
                        <ul>
                            <li></li>
                            <li><label for="language" class="select"></label> <select
                                name="language" id="language" class="lang" data-corners="false"
                                data-iconpos="noicon" onchange="trans($(this));">
                                    <option value="english">En</option>
                                    <option value="dutch">Nl</option>
                                    <option value="german">De</option>
                            </select></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <!-- Content -->
                </div>
                <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
                    <div data-role="navbar">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#one" class="ui-disabled">Vorige</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#two">Volgende</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="formContent" data-role="page" id="two">
                <div data-role="header" class="ui-header-fixed">
                    <div data-role="navbar">
                        <ul>
                            <li></li>
                            <li><label for="language" class="select"></label> <select
                                name="language" id="language" class="lang" data-corners="false"
                                data-iconpos="noicon" onchange="trans($(this));">
                                    <option value="english">En</option>
                                    <option value="dutch">Nl</option>
                                    <option value="german">De</option>
                            </select>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <!-- Content -->
                </div>
                <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
                    <div data-role="navbar">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#one">Vorige</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#two" class="ui-disabled">Volgende</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        translate($('.lang').val());
        function trans(it){
            var v = it.val();
            translate(v);
            $(".lang option[value='" + v + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

translate(); contains the translation.
The last line of the trans() function should set the selected option of both selectors.

Now when i select a language on the first page, the selected value on both selectors change. But when i select a language on the second page, the selected value does not change on both selectors.

Why is this and how do i solve it?

### Edit

Finally got that working:

```
    $(document).on('change', '#language', function () {
        var v = $(this).val();
        translate(v);
        $("#language option").removeAttr('selected');
        $("#language option[value='" + v + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
        $("#language").selectmenu("refresh");
    });
```

Now the select menu's don't refresh. In the source code (using firebug) the correct item is selected, but in the front-end it displays the wrong item. Seems like selectmenu('refresh'); doesn't do the trick.

### Solved

I ended up setting the display value myself:

```
$(document).on('change', '#language', function () {
        var v = $(this).val();
        translate(v);
        $("#language option").removeAttr('selected');
        $("#language option[value='" + v + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
        $(".ui-header .ui-navbar .ui-grid-a .ui-block-b .ui-select .ui-btn .ui-btn-inner .ui-btn-text span").html(v);
    });
```

Don't mind the long selector, i just want to be sure i have the correct dropdown ;)

Comment: provide full code, whee are you calling onChange for select?

Comment: in the <select> tag is an onchange which calls trans();

Comment: post your full code so I can see how are you referencing and switching pages

Comment: added full code. (volgende = next, vorige = previous. in dutch)

Comment: hm when i have visited the second page, the first page has the same problem.. edit: it only works correctly the first time i select a language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting the display value myself:

```
<label for="language" class="select"></label> <select
                                name="language" id="language" class="lang" data-corners="false"
                                data-iconpos="noicon">
                                    <option value="En">Lang</option>
                                    <option value="En">En</option>
                                    <option value="Nl">Nl</option>
                                    <option value="De">De</option>
                            </select>

$(document).on('change', '#language', function () {
        var v = $(this).val();
        translate(v);
        $("#language option").removeAttr('selected');
        $("#language option[value='" + v + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
        $(".ui-header .ui-navbar .ui-grid-a .ui-block-b .ui-select .ui-btn .ui-btn-inner .ui-btn-text .lang").html(v);
    });
```

Don't mind the long selector, i just want to be sure i have the correct dropdown ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing this in 2 sperate files let's say index.html and contact.html for example , when you call the second page using jqm it uses ajax request to load the content of the second , and by content I mean the body only , ajax request does not load what is found outside the `<body></body>` tag so if your script is found in `<head></head>` or at the end of the file it will not be loaded and you have two solutions:
1) write your script inside the body and mainly after the div or the form
2) if you are calling the page through a link add the attribute `data-ajax="false` to your anchor tag so it prevents jqm of using ajax

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. But i'm using 1 file ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your listview AND/OR select at the end of your translation-function:

```
<script>
        translate($('.lang').val());
        function trans(it){
            var v = it.val();
            translate(v);
            $(".lang option[value='" + v + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
            $('#giveAnIDtoYourListview').listview('refresh');
            $('#giveAnIDtoYourSelect').selectmenu('refresh');
        }
    </script>
```

Listview: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

Select: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/selects/methods.html

Comment: did you also try working with the .onClick function in JQM on second page? perhaps onChange does not work on second page because of the JQ framework in some way...

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I tried using $('.lang').change(function(){}); but same result

Comment: use a button on second page, call onClick when pressing the button, execute your trans function in there. if this is working you know, that you can't use onChange in HTML on jqueries second page! http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-events.html
onchange is simple javascript, perhaps it does not align with jquery.

Comment: Well, the weird thing is, it does work as expected the first time. Gonna try your suggestion

Comment: Same result.. also tried $(document).on('change', '#language', function () {}); same result